# Exporting SQL query to xml document in Excel using SSIS

Tags: excel, xml, ssis

Have been racking my brains on this one. I want to create an output from a simple SQL query and pass it into an xml document type within Excel. This means that the end result must be openable via excel but remains an xml document (with saved extension of .xml).  I'd hoped I could use Excel as a 'Destination' but it will not recognise .xml formats.

On top of that my xml excel file has multiple tabs and the data should be exported to a set tab and line number.

Anyone have a suggestion for how to have SSIS export this correctly for me?
At the moment am having to copy/paste from SQL to the excel directly!

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what XML has to do with this??? Do you mean xlsx?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I mean the files are .xml files which are opened via Microsoft Excel. The extension is clearly .xml but Excel destination does not recognise this as a format.